# How do I mock objects in the new coreclr world?

Tags: c#, mocking, asp.net-core, dnx, coreclr

I have always been using [Moq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Moq/) for mocking external dependencies while unit testing. Now that I am trying to make my code completely cross platform, I want to make my unit tests run on linux too and so I am targeting my project coreclr50.

The issue is I can't seem to find any mocking libraries that would enable me to mock on coreclr. [LightMock.vNext](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LightMock.vNext/) has attempted to do it, but it requires creating mock classes manually which is not convenient.

I wonder how are people unit testing their MVC 6 controllers!

Answer (score 2):

The ASP.NET team seems to be using Moq https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/test/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core.Test/project.json:

```
 "dnxcore50": {
  "dependencies": {
    "moq.netcore": "4.4.0-beta8"
  }
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that that version is **not official**. It is just a fork,

Answer (score 1):

NSubstitute is a great mocking framework. As far as I can see they don't directly support coreclr yet, but they have a pull request on GitHub for that:

https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/pull/197

So you can try to do it yourself or wait a bit. Moq was a good framework, but as far as I remember it's not maintained for a long time now. NSubstitute has nicer syntax as well (at least IMHO :)